# Getting multiple drop down list value from view using JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

I am trying to use JSF to retrieve multiple drop down lists according to user input from the view to controller.

However seems I cannot find the correct way.

As the drop down lists are generated dynamically, I cannot hard code the id / name of the drop down list.

Here is my code in the view:

```
<ui:repeat var="file" value="#{uploadBean.filesInZip}" varStatus="status">  
                        <tr>  
                            <td><h:outputText value="#{file.name}" /></td>  
                            <td>  
                                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{uploadBean.studentSelections}">  
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{uploadBean.students}" var="student"   
                                        itemLabel="#{student.firstName}, #{student.lastName} (#{student.userId})"   
                                        itemValue="#{student.id}"/>  
                                </h:selectOneMenu>  
                            </td>  
                        </tr>  
</ui:repeat>
```

So could anyone give a hand on it?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating multiple `<h:selectOneMenu>` with the same value.

What you could do is create a `HashMap<Integer, T>` of your `uploadBean.studentSelections`, where each `<T>` match one file in your zip.

Then you can use `<h:selectOneMenu value="#{uploadBean.studentSelections[status]}">`

You can of course reuse `uploadBean.students` to populate each of your `<f:selectItems>`.